# Android R.anim.files cannot be found

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I am not sure if it is only me but strangely, I cannot access slide_in_right.xml and slide_out_left.xml inside res/anim that I created

 I am using this line of code to access the animation

```
UserProfile.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_right, android.R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

However, it underlines the slide_in_right and slide_out_left saying that it cannot Resolve symbol.

Methods tried:
1. Clean the project
       Still cannot Resolve symbol for both android.R.anim.slide_in_right and 
    android.R.anim.slide_out_left
2. Rebuild project 
       Gives me an error saying **error: cannot find symbol variable slide_in_right** 
3. Double checked if i spelled the anim uncorrectly but it seem to be correct

Some information:
------------------
Android Studio 1.5.1
Build #Al-141.2456560, built on December 1, 2015
JRE: 1.7.0_79-b15 x86_64

Did anyone came across this problem before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have created the animation files inside your project, this should use your project **R** reference instead of **android.R.** Try to use like this.

```
UserProfile.this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

Comment: @BlueFishy you are welcome. Please accept the answer if it helped you.